# Influence of pressure on thermal conductivity of water vapour (steam)

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, water, thermal-conductivity

I am looking for an analytical correlation of the thermal conductivity of water vapour (steam) in function of pressure. Apparently the effect is not large, but I would like to confirm this by some correlations.

The only thing I found so far is this plot from The Engineering Toolbox. Unfortunately, no sources/references are given.

Thanks!

[image: Thermal conductivity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Transport Phenomena, Chapter 9 presents molecular derivation of pure species thermal conductivity as a function of temperature and pressure, and, in Section 9.2 presents a Corresponding States plot of reduced thermal conductivity as a function of reduced temperature and reduced pressure.  At low pressures, all the curves converge to a limiting curve that is a function only of reduced temperature.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the [International Association for the Properties of Water and Steam](http://www.iapws.org) who provide guidelines for the experimental determination, as well as semi-empirical formulations of the properties that you're interested in.  Their formulations have been coded up by several sources including the NIST (FORTRAN, non-free) and [this rather cool version in python](https://github.com/tomduck/myiapws).